# How can I have a same domain iframe disable same domain scripting

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have two pages which live within the same folder,

1) index.php
2) test.html

On test.html, there is an iframe with index.php as the source.

However, I'd like to disable javascript access to index.php from test.html. In other words, index.php should act like its on a different domain, even though it is on the same domain.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most simplest way, is it possible for you to create a alias sub-domain pointing to your server? if so you can do that by doing following:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php
```

and then call test.html by

```
http://myaliasdomain.com/test.html
```

See if this is possible or else we can think of different solution.

Comment: Would definitely be helpful when testing remotely, but I'd rather have a solution which works locally (if possible).

Comment: hmm, what you can do is you can update your hosts irrespective of whether you're on windows or linux. just add an entry with "<ip-addr> domain-name" and you're done..don't remove any entry from hosts file just add new line. Location of hosts file on windows is "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts".